# Exportar tabla de BD a archivo .txt en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Necesito exportar una base de datos a un archivo .txt delimitado por comas, he investigado pero no encuentro la manera, necesito que los archivos se muestren de esta forma:

> Dato, Dato, Dato
>   Dato, Dato, Dato

**¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?**

Comment: Agrega lo que has realizado o tratado, agrega un ejemplo de tu Base de datos!, revisa [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Tenés dos formas que se me ocurren:

1) Conectarte por consola usando `adb`.
Una vez conectado lo que tenés es una terminal unix y tenes que hacer cd hasta la carpta de tu app (`/data/data/<nombre de paquete>`), y luego cd a la carpeta `databases`.
En esa carpeta vas a ver tu base de datos (termina con .db). Para abrirla ejecutas `slqlite3 <nombre de la base de datos incluyendo la extensión>`
Eso abre la consola de `sqlite` y podés haces queries y ver los datos de tu base, y creo que también enviar los resultados a un archivo en tu pc.

2) Con Android Studio podes abrir el explorador de archivos (`View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer`), buscar la base de datos en la carpeta descripta en el item anterior, y descargar el archivo de la base de datos a tu pc.
Una vez descargado, te instalas `SQLite` (https://www.sqlite.org) y puedes abrir el archivo en tu computadora. Desde ahí puedes ejecutar queries y guardar consultas como archivo txt.

Comment: Algun motivo para el voto negativo?